# close document action() level in pdf javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to show an alert when user close the document, i added this code to `Tools>Javascript> Set document action>document will close`

I am trying to show this alert `app.alert("this document will close, have a nice day");` in adobe acrobat `javascript`

but when i try to close the document, the alert is not working!.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the action close will not work unless you did not save your changes in the document.